# How to filter post objects in django according to a particular user model field?

Tags: django

I'm currently creating a Social platform with Django. Right now, I'm developing homepage and want to show posts matching a userfield.
This is my Post model:

```
class Discussion(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

This is user account model:

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    classid = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

This is view:

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        discussions = Discussion.objects.get(post=Account.classid).order_by('-date')
        form = PostDiscussionForm()
        return render(request, 'app/home.html', {'discussions':discussions,'form':form})

    else:
        form = PostDiscussionForm(request.POST)
        newdisscussion = form.save(commit=False)
        newdisscussion.author = request.user
        newdisscussion.save()
        return redirect('home')
```

I want to show only logged users matching their classid (from user account model)

Answer (score 0):

What I gather from here, is that you want to show which users are currently online/logged in? For that you'll need to store additional information when logging like, add a boolean field in the user model indicating whether or not the user has logged in and then filter based on that field.

```py
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    logged_in = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    classid = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Now add additional logic which sets this field to true when the user eventually logs in from your `/login` route.

Then Filter using:

```
$ return Account.objects.filter(logged_in==True)
```

This will return you all users that have currently logged in, if you're not using any `serializers`, than use `value_list` for getting the values only rather than the whole user objects.

```
$ return Account.objects.filter(logged_in==True).values_list('classid', flat=True)
```

Comment: discussion = Discussion.object.get(post=Account.classid) is not working .. How can make post appear by matching their classid value?

Comment: `.get`  method on a model field, only takes primary keys, and ideally other than getting an object by a primary key, you can use a foreign unique key, neither is satisifed by your database model.

Comment: `Discussion.objects.filter(post=Account.classid)` if you are storing `classid` in `post` field, which I don't recommend, use foreign keys.